# Android App strange behaviour when comeing back from sleep

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opengl-es

since i am stuck on this problem and don't know where my mistake is I need to ask you guys.
When I first launch my app everything works fine, but when i press the "back" button on my phone to get back to main screen and start the app again (which is not a real new startup because app goes to sleep) it has a really strange behaviour.

I am using opengles to draw a texture onto the screen and when I make a touch the texture changes. The touch sets a boolean to true that indicates to draw the other texture. But somehow it is always false when I test its value even when it just got written to true from touch event. I was wondering because that only happens when I pressed the "back" button on the phone. When I am returning to main screen with the home button and then moving back to the app this thing doesnt occur and everything works.

First I thought it is something with the threads 2 different threads(activity rendering thread and surfaceview thread for touch events) but even when synchronizing all get/set methods it still doesnt work. I am starting to think that the touch thread thing is still operating on old objects and changes values there while the references in the rendering thread get newly instanciated so the boolean is set by touch but the rendering thread only takes the default value because they got different objects what is obviously somehow not possible.

Well I am at end of my knowledge so please enlighten me

Edit: Well I found the mistake... When the device came back from sleep it created another object(the textured square) and then the touch event occured on the old one which was not delted and the new one got drawn.

Also it would be nice if somebody could tell me which exact methods get called when it comes back from sleep? Is it only onResume or are there more? And what about references, do they get also deleted because there shouldnt be created another object, I even test for == null and then create a new one but somehow this seems to be true when it comes back

Comment: Can you post the gl renderer code and also the part where the boolean flag is set from the touch events. It might help us more in solving the issue

Answer (score 0):

as answer to your second question, you can learn more on activity life cycle here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

What I usually do is to have a resource manager that knows what has been loaded and handles life cycle of textures, models, etc. When my app goes to stopped or paused, the resource manager unloads resources (you may don't do that when paused, only on stopped) and when the app is resumed, reload all resources and regenerate the OpenGL context (remember that unless you do something, ie state that at the manifest, the system will destroy the OpenGL context). You need to setup textures, buffer objects and so on. You can extend this idea to handle everything that needs to be persisted during the application life cycle.

Happy coding!